# Advanced installer Logging Based on Condition

Tags: logging, installation, windows-installer, advanced-installer

I am trying to enable logging from advanced installer itself based on some condition.
I can turn on the log without a problem thanks to some forums in advanced isntaller by :

- open your installation package's Advanced Installer project
- go to the Media page and select the Bootstrapper tab
- check the Create EXE setup file option
- set the MSI Command Line field to: /L*V "C:\package.log"

My problem is the condition. I want it to do this only if say "Property X is 1" .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to have conditional command lines in the bootstrapper built by AI. A solution would be to duplicate the current build and set a different command line for it, i.e. one that does or does not create a log.

Also, it is kind of purposeless to thing about conditioning the command line by setting a property from the command line. I mean, if you still need to set the property when launching the setup, can't just set a different command line? (to log or not the MSI install)